# Passing Parameters to Search box for Refined Results

Tags: search, search-results, refiner, refinement-panel

Couldn't find a similar request before. Is there a way to pass a parameter (page metadata column) value to the Search box so that it applies the metadata column value as a Refiner in the Search Results.

For context, all pages in our SharePoint site have an Business Unit managed metadata column. The Search is configured to search the entire site that can be refined through a Refinement panel. However users do not like to have to click the Business Unit refiner panel as an added step to get the results they want. They would prefer the results automatically display results based on their business unit. Because of the way user profiles are set up, it may be more effort to map the Business Unit to the Organization field in the profiles. All users do start at their Business Unit home page and largely stay within their Business Unit pages even when searching, which takes me to my question:

Is there a way to pass the Business Unit metadata column value for the page the user is on to the Search so that the Search Results is initially refined based on the starting point. The user can then clear the Refiner if they want to search outside their Business area.